# Install Tensorflow on M1 Mac. Cant make it work

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am trying to use Tensorflow on my Macbook Pro with the M1 Pro Chip. I red a lot of articles and watched videos, but I cant make it work. My latest try was with the following conda env and the code was just importing Tensorflow in a python file an running it.

Thats the error message:

```
2022-12-28 19:14:01.671088: F tensorflow/c/experimental/stream_executor/stream_executor.cc:808] Non-OK-status: stream_executor::MultiPlatformManager::RegisterPlatform( std::move(cplatform)) status: INTERNAL: platform is already registered with name: "METAL"
[1]    1296 abort      /opt/homebrew/bin/python
```

and this is my file to create the env:

```
name: tf-metal
channels:
  - apple
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10 
  - pip
  - jupyter
  - tensorflow-deps
  - pandas
  - pandas-datareader
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
  - ipykernel

  ## PyPI packages
  - pip:
    - tensorflow-macos
    - tensorflow-metal
```

I also tried running it with jupyter notebook, but then my kernel keeps crashing.

My feeling is some people can make it work on m1 and some can't... like me :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem for quite a while and also had many issues getting the solutions proposed in tutorials and such to work for me. What I believe to be the problem (though I'm by no means completely certain of this) is existing or cached versions of some of the required packages that stick around even after I try to reinstall the correct ones. Those existing packages don't work with the arm64 architecture that the M1 chip uses. Its application specific, so your numpy installation will be just fine, but it causes issues with tensorflow (and a few other gpu applications I've seen other people wrestling with)

I was able to solve this issue by using conda channels to force it to only look within a specific channel (and thus only at our spiffy new arm64 architecture compliant packages) when searching for dependancies instead of looking for existing installations and finding old ones.

I didn't create the environment from a file instead using the command

```
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
```

If there is a way to directly do this within the environment file I'm not familiar with it, however there are some pretty easy work arounds to have the same effect. The easiest in my opinion would be to specify the channel for all the relevant packages like so

```
name: tf-metal
channels:
  - apple

dependencies:
  - python=3.10 
  - pip
  - jupyter
  - apple::tensorflow-deps
  - conda-forge::pandas
  - conda-forge::pandas-datareader
  - conda-forge::scikit-learn
  - conda-forge::scipy
  - conda-forge::ipykernel

  ## PyPI packages
  - pip:
    - tensorflow-macos
    - tensorflow-metal
```

I did some testing on my end and this also allowed me to successfully install it though it took about a minute and a half to run. Here's the test file I used as well:

```
# This function is written to help users ensure that their tensorflow installations are correct
print("Testing Tensorflow Validity", flush = True)
import tensorflow as tf

print("[TensorFlow] version:", tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for your answer. Sadly I tried it and it didnt worked... I also tried changing it up or using different sources with your way of doing it. I got my conda config changed(I could see with "conda config --show-sources") and I tried creating my env with the file you provided.

Then I got error with incompatible versions of all the packages. I also cleared the old packages in my installation with "python -m pip cache purge" and after some attempts it ran through the creating process. But I have the same error like in the beginning and I cant reproduce the old errors...